# Float:left, div caindo pela largura da div

Tags: html, css

Estou com um problema com o `float:left;`: para uma largura maior que a página a `div` cai, mas eu queria que continuasse a `div` anterior.

HTML:

```html
<div id="menu" class="menu">
    MENU
</div>
<div class="resto">
    RESTO DO CONTEUDO
</div>
```

CSS:

```css
.menu {
    width: 250px;
    float: left;
    position: blocked;
    background-color: blue;
}

.resto {
    background-color: #ccc;
    width: 100%;
    float: right;
}
```

[Resultado no JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/UUzhm/2/embedded/result/).

Answer (score 3):

Você não precisa do `overflow: hidden;`, retirando a `width` e o `float: right;` ela já vai para a mesma linha.

O bom seria você colocar uma width nas duas `div's` e deixa-las num bloco para evitar conflitos com elementos abaixo deles.

Veja o código no [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/UUzhm/5/)

Com isso você cria blocos no seu código e evita que elementos abaixo deles "quebrem" a página.

Bons estudos!

Answer (score 2):

Pelo que me parece queres por a `div` fixa na linha.
Faltava-te a propriedade `overflow: hidden;` que faz isso mesmo.

[Fiddle editado](http://jsfiddle.net/cesarmiguel/UUzhm/3/)

Comment: Muito obrigado consegui resolver o meu problema

Comment: Sempre bem vindo! Nota: Se respondi à sua questão coloque a mesma com a resposta correta

Comment: eu coloquei a resposta do meu poblema,fiz certo??

Comment: Não, na resposta que eu dei está um visto/correcto. Basta clicar lá.